# Long Press Gesture Recognizer location(in: view) not correctly calculating location

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm using a `UIScrollView` to display an image with various markers on top. The image view has a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` that detects long presses. When the long press event is detected, I want to create a new marker at that location.

The problem I'm having is that when I zoom in or out, the location of the gesture recognizer's `location(in: view)` seems to be off. Here's a snippet of my implementation:

```
let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onLongPress(gesture:)))
self.hostingController.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)
```

```
@objc func onLongPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            guard let view = gesture.view else { break }
            let location = gesture.location(in: view)
            let pinPointWidth = 32.0
            let pinPointHeight = 42.0
            let x = location.x - (pinPointWidth / 2)
            let y = location.y - pinPointHeight
            let finalLocation = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            self.onLongPress(finalLocation)
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm using a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` that contains a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView` that is surfaced to my SwiftUI View. Maybe this might be causing it.

Here's the SwiftUI code:

```
var body: some View {
    UIScrollViewWrapper(scaleFactor: $scaleFactor, onLongPress: onInspectionCreated) {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Image(uiImage: image)
            ForEach(filteredInspections, id: \.syncToken) { inspection in
               InspectionMarkerView(
                    scaleFactor: scaleFactor,
                    xLocation: CGFloat(inspection.xLocation),
                    yLocation: CGFloat(inspection.yLocation),
                    iconName: iconNameForInspection(inspectionMO: inspection),
                    label: inspection.readableIdPaddedOrNewInspection)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedInspection = inspection
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .clipped()
}
```

Here's a link to a reproducible example project:
https://github.com/Kukiwon/sample-project-zoom-long-press-location

Here's a recording of the problem:
[Link to video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGdFT.jpg)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's going on from that video clip. Best bet is to put together a [mre] (post it somewhere like GitHub) so we can see exactly what's happening.

Comment: @DonMag Here you go: https://github.com/Kukiwon/sample-project-zoom-long-press-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use SwiftUI, but I've seen some quirky stuff looking at `UIHostingController` implementations, and it appears a specific quirk is hitting you.

I inset your scroll view by 40-pts and gave the main view a red background to make it a little easier to see what's going on.

First, add a 2-pixel blue line around the border of your `sheet_hd` image, and scroll all the way to the bottom-left corner. It should look like this:

[image]

As you zoom in, keeping the scroll at bottom-left, it will look like this:

[image]

So far, so good -- and using a long-press to add a marker works as expected.

However, as soon as we zoom out to less than 1.0 zoom scale:

[image]

we can no longer see the bottom edge of the image.

Zooming back in makes it more obvious:

[image]

And the long-press location is incorrect.

For further clarification, if we set `.clipsToBounds = false` on the scroll view, and set `.alpha = 0.5` on the image view, we see this:

[image]

We can drag the view up to see the bottom edge, but as soon as we release the touch is bounces back below the frame of the scroll view.

What *should* fix this is to use this extension:

```
// extension to remove safe area from UIHostingController
//  source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70339424/6257435
extension UIHostingController {
    convenience public init(rootView: Content, ignoreSafeArea: Bool) {
        self.init(rootView: rootView)
        
        if ignoreSafeArea {
            disableSafeArea()
        }
    }
    
    func disableSafeArea() {
        guard let viewClass = object_getClass(view) else { return }
        
        let viewSubclassName = String(cString: class_getName(viewClass)).appending("_IgnoreSafeArea")
        if let viewSubclass = NSClassFromString(viewSubclassName) {
            object_setClass(view, viewSubclass)
        }
        else {
            guard let viewClassNameUtf8 = (viewSubclassName as NSString).utf8String else { return }
            guard let viewSubclass = objc_allocateClassPair(viewClass, viewClassNameUtf8, 0) else { return }
            
            if let method = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, #selector(getter: UIView.safeAreaInsets)) {
                let safeAreaInsets: @convention(block) (AnyObject) -> UIEdgeInsets = { _ in
                    return .zero
                }
                class_addMethod(viewSubclass, #selector(getter: UIView.safeAreaInsets), imp_implementationWithBlock(safeAreaInsets), method_getTypeEncoding(method))
            }
            
            objc_registerClassPair(viewSubclass)
            object_setClass(view, viewSubclass)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in `viewDidLoad()` in your `UIScrollViewViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
    self.pinEdges(of: self.scrollView, to: self.view)
    
    // add this line
    self.hostingController.disableSafeArea()
    
    self.hostingController.willMove(toParent: self)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(self.hostingController.view)
    self.pinEdges(of: self.hostingController.view, to: self.scrollView)
    self.hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
    self.hostingController.view.alpha = 0
}
```

Quick testing (obviously, you'll want to thoroughly test it) seems good... we can scroll all the way to the bottom, and long-press location is back where it should be.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The extension seems to solve the problem indeed.